# Disable New e-mail button in Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have an existing Outlook Add-In that was developed for a client for Outlook 2003/2007. One of the requirements was that the add-in would disable the default New email button on the toolbar. I was able to do this by accessing the CommandBars object of the Explorer windows.

They are now looking at migrating the tool to Outlook 2010. Obviously the CommandBars object is no longer available, and I have not been able to find anything regarding programmatically disabling any of the built-in buttons on the ribbon.

1. Is it possible to programmatically change the state of any of the built-in buttons?
2. Any suggestions here would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If group policy is an option, the "right" way to do this in Outlook 2010 is via group policy settings.  From Technet:

"Verify that you have the necessary security permissions for the GPO: either Edit settings or Edit settings, delete, and modify security. For more information about permissions that are needed to manage Group Policy, see “Delegating administration of Group Policy” in the Group Policy Planning and Deployment Guide (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=182208).

In Group Policy Object Editor console, expand User Configuration, expand Administrative Templates, and then expand the application for which you want to disable commands (for example, double-click Microsoft Excel 2010).

Click Disable items in User Interface, click Predefined, double-click Disable commands, click Enabled, select the commands that you want to disable, and then click OK."

Full documentation here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179143.aspx#section3

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much - they are certainly a candidate for something like this.  I'll take it to their IT department and see what they think.